# Does 'like' clause work on double precision (used for latitude/longitude) data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, latitude-longitude

I am trying to run SQL 'LIKE' clause query on a column which has data type as 'double precision'. However, I cannot execute the query. I wanted to check if the records in that column have text/special characters using LIKE clause

select latitude from geoData where latitude like '%[^0-9]%'

Comment: I would consider this a good thing.  What are you trying to do.

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't take regular expressions but it does use `%`. `RLIKE` takes regular expressions, but `%` is not a regular expression character, it just means literally "percentage character". Regular expressions are also intended to work on character data, not numbers. For numbers use ranges like `BETWEEN ? AND ?`.

Answer (score 2):

A double precision number is stored as a *number* in the database.  There is no possibility that any other characters can be stored in the value -- because there are no characters at all.

So, you don't need to perform your check.  You might want to validate that the values are between -180 and 180, if you want a data validity check.

Comment: Excellent! This helps a lot. I am working on PostGIS data types for the first time and coming from traditional knowledge of data types. 
So for checking values should > or < 180/-180 work?

Comment: @VishwalShah . . . For this purpose you an use `col between -180 and 180`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon research, I found out that double precision is a completely numeric data type. Therefore any special characters will not be part of it at all